# JWT Token not found when I am trying to access secured endpoints with apl platform (admin component)

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I am trying to build my API with API Platform (Symfony 4) and everything seems to be fine but when I am using admin component to access **secured endpoints** (after I have been logged in successfully) server always returns 401 "JWT Token not found". I've found that **Admin component** is not sending the **'Authorization' header with token** so server can't check token to authorize a request.

Since the Admin login works fine and token is always stored in localStorage (after successful login) I've tried to send a request with **cURL** and **Postman** with the stored token and server always returns valid response.

Any idea?

## Update 1

I am using code from API Platform documentation (https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/authentication-support/#authentication-support).

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import parseHydraDocumentation from '@api-platform/api-doc-parser/lib/hydra/parseHydraDocumentation';
import {fetchHydra as baseFetchHydra, HydraAdmin, hydraClient} from '@api-platform/admin';
import authProvider from './authProvider';
import {Redirect, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const entrypoint = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT;
const fetchHeaders = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`};
const fetchHydra = (url, options = {}) => baseFetchHydra(url, {
  ...options,
  headers: new Headers(fetchHeaders),
});
const dataProvider = api => hydraClient(api, fetchHydra);
const apiDocumentationParser = entrypoint =>
  parseHydraDocumentation(entrypoint, {
    headers: new Headers(fetchHeaders),
  }).then(
    ({api}) => ({api}),
    result => {
      const {api, status} = result;

      if (status === 401) {
        return Promise.resolve({
          api,
          status,
          customRoutes: [
            <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/login"/>}/>,
          ],
        });
      }

      return Promise.reject(result);
    }
  );

export default () => (
  <HydraAdmin
    apiDocumentationParser={apiDocumentationParser}
    authProvider={authProvider}
    entrypoint={entrypoint}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
  />
);
```

**authProvider.js**

```
import {AUTH_CHECK, AUTH_ERROR, AUTH_LOGIN, AUTH_LOGOUT} from 'react-admin';

const authenticationTokenUri = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT}/authentication_token`;

export default (type, params) => {
  switch (type) {
    case AUTH_LOGIN:
      const {username, password} = params;
      const request = new Request(authenticationTokenUri, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({email: username, password}),
        headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
      });

      return fetch(request)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) throw new Error(response.statusText);

          return response.json();
        })
        .then(({token}) => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', token); 
          window.location.replace('/');
        });

    case AUTH_LOGOUT:
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      break;

    case AUTH_ERROR:
      if (401 === params.status || 403 === params.status) {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');

        return Promise.reject();
      }
      break;

    case AUTH_CHECK:
      return localStorage.getItem('token') ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();

    default:
      return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

## Update 2

I have found that the authorization header with token is sent with some requests, but all requests to API endpoints are sent without authorization header that results in 401.

[dev tools network img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSCiS.png)

[correct request headers img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHdVU.png)

[a endpoint request headers - miss authorization header img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1O2R.png)

[dev tools console log img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiVLO.png)

## Update 3

**security.yaml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/authentication_token
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
         # api platform has prefix /api
         - { path: ^/api/authentication_token$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/api/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

**lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml**

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
```

**Greeting entity**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * This is a dummy entity. Remove it!
 *
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Greeting
{
    /**
     * @var int The entity Id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string A nice person
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $name = '';

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

## Update 4

As you can see a request to a secured endpoint with Postman works.
[Postman printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzzLl.png)

Comment: you to set the  Authorization Header with the retrieved token yourself?
It is well documented in the Api-Platform docs.

Comment: No, i haven't set the Authorization Header myself, I am using code from API Platform documentation (I've updated question and pasted full code which I am using).

Comment: It is pretty much what i did, this should work. Is your token set correctly in the local storage or are there any error messages?

Comment: Yes it is. I have found that the authorization header with token is sent with some requests, but all requests to API endpoints are sent without authorization header that results in 401. I've attached printscreens from dev tools to question update.

Comment: Strange. Can you post your security and lexik_jwt_authentication configs and the greeting Entity ? maybe i see something there

Comment: I've put code from the security.yaml and the lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml files in third update.

Comment: do you have any access_control annotation on your Entities?

Comment: Hmm. How are you able to login if the /api/authentication_token is secured by access control (IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY)? This is confusing.

Comment: No, i don't have any access_control annotation on any Entity. I've post greeting Entity.

Comment: Yes you are right, I've forgot to add access to a login path so I've updated the security.yaml in Update 3 but a token has been always correctly returned and stored in localStorage (weird). Anyway as you can see in Update 4, request with Postman works and endpoint returns correct data.

Comment: Hello, Did you find the solution? I'm facing the same problem :(

Comment: For me, the bug occurs during first login (after refresh). But, if you refresh the page, the app is authorized properly, and any logins after that (without refreshing) works properly. It seems that on first login (after refreshing), the header "Authorization" is sent with value "null". I think the token was retrieved from localStorage before it was set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, downgrading the "@api-platform/admin" from "⁰0.6.3" to "0.6.2" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your Auth Header yourself. It won't be done by default.

```
const fetchHeaders = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`};
const fetchHydra = (url, options = {}) => baseFetchHydra(url, {
    ...options,
    headers: new Headers(fetchHeaders),
});
```

Comment: see here: https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/authentication-support/#authentication-support